# Normalization values too small or overflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, curve-fitting, normalization

I have a simple NN in PyTorch (new to it). I am trying to fit values for the [Sellmeier Equation](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Materials/#sellmeier-coefficients).

My network is pretty simple:

```
self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(self.input_count, self.input_count * self.hidden_layer_scalar), 
    nn.ReLU(), 
    nn.Linear(
            self.input_count * self.hidden_layer_scalar, 
            self.input_count * self.hidden_layer_scalar
        ), 
    nn.ReLU(), 
    nn.Linear(self.input_count * self.hidden_layer_scalar, self.sellmeirer_term_count * 2)
)
```

For each step I take the output layer (the coefficients) and put it into the Sellmeier function to get the output, then compute the loss from that (please excuse the spelling mistake)

```
def forward(self, inputs): 
    self.sellmeirer_coefficients = self.linear_relu_stack(inputs)
    self.compute_refractive_indicies()
    return self.output_refractive_indicies 
def compute_refractive_indicies(self): 
    self.output_refractive_indicies = sellmeirer3(
             self.wave_lengths, 
             *tuple(self.sellmeirer_coefficients)# * self.sellmeirer_scalar) <-- This comment is very relevant to the question
        )
    return self.output_refractive_indicies
#...

def train(device, model, loss_function, optimizer, total_iteration_count): 
    model.train()
    progress_output = "Starting up"
    for current_iteration in range(total_iteration_count): 
        parameters = model.parameters_to_array().to(device)
        prediction = model(parameters)
        loss = loss_function(prediction, model.refractive_indicies) # refractive_indicies and wave_lengths come from data
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    return model, model.sellmeirer_coefficients
```

The Sellmeier coefficients come out as values between -1 and 1, but I think that may not be the range of values I need (too small probably, based on the output being too small). So I tried to scale up the coefficients when computing refractive indices, then use the known refractive indices + the computed in the loss function for feedback. Even if I do not integrate the multiplied Sellmeier Coefficients back into the input layer (only the ones on the scale -1 to 1), and normalize the refractive indices (computed and from data) to such a scale, the Sellmeier Coefficients blow up, and the input layer receives values that eventually overflow (10^(30+something) for 32 but float and 10^(n * 100) for an n somewhere less than about 4 or 5), leading to nan's.

I don't really know why this multiplication, which does not discretely feed into the network, causes this, how can I get the neural network to output outside of the range-1 to 1, taking as input including its previous output (Sellmeier Coefficients, but also: refractive indices from data, computed refractive indices, wavelengths), and learn from it? Why does scaling it cause it to blow up?

The normalization I was doing I think was a bit off, however, while tweaks I made do help, at one point I got NaN's after about 100k steps of training. Sellmeier Coefficients do seem to get out of the range of -1 to 1. Is this erroneous?

After 1000000 steps, the values of Sellmeier coefficients seemed to normalize from -1 to 1 again. Also, no NaNs that I saw. But I have a feeling it may get NaN's the somehow "jog" itself out.